# How to print filenames in directory?

Tags: python

How can I print all filenames in a directory using python? Why isn't this working?

```
for file in glob.glob("*"): 
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. I think you're just missing the import. Try:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob("*"): 
    print(file)
```